# Testing using Wiremock to test a Feign Client

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, wiremock, spring-cloud-feign

So I've spent a good day trying to figure this out and it's been quite difficult. 
So the issue is that when you have a simple client using Feign as below:

```
@FeignClient(name = "identity-service")
public interface IdentityClient {

    @GetMapping(value = "/")
    String request();
}
```

And of course your application is annotated with the `@EnableFeignClients` as below:

```
@EnableEurekaClient
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableFeignClients
public class LicenseServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(LicenseServiceApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

If I have a test for that feign client as below:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment= SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.NONE)
public class LicenseServiceTest {

    @ClassRule
    public static WireMockClassRule wiremock = new WireMockClassRule(
        WireMockSpring.options().dynamicPort());

    // A service that calls out over HTTP
    @Autowired
    private IdentityClient identityClient;

    // Using the WireMock APIs in the normal way:
    @Test
    public void contextLoads() throws Exception {
        stubFor(get(urlEqualTo("/"))
            .willReturn(aResponse().withHeader("Content-Type", 
                     "text/plain").withBody("Hello World!")));
    // We're asserting if WireMock responded properly
    assertThat(this.identityClient.request()).isEqualTo("Hello World!");
    }

}
```

It generates the following stacktrace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.netflix.client.ClientException: Load balancer does not have available server for client: identity-service

    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.feign.ribbon.LoadBalancerFeignClient.execute(LoadBalancerFeignClient.java:71)
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.executeAndDecode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:97)
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.invoke(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:76)
    at feign.ReflectiveFeign$FeignInvocationHandler.invoke(ReflectiveFeign.java:103)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy122.request(Unknown Source)
    at com.gov.zw.service.LicenseServiceTest.contextLoads(LicenseServiceTest.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.junit.WireMockClassRule$1.evaluate(WireMockClassRule.java:70)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: com.netflix.client.ClientException: Load balancer does not have available server for client: identity-service
    at com.netflix.loadbalancer.LoadBalancerContext.getServerFromLoadBalancer(LoadBalancerContext.java:483)
    at com.netflix.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerCommand$1.call(LoadBalancerCommand.java:184)
    at com.netflix.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerCommand$1.call(LoadBalancerCommand.java:180)
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeConcatMap.call(OnSubscribeConcatMap.java:94)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeConcatMap.call(OnSubscribeConcatMap.java:42)
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorRetryWithPredicate$SourceSubscriber$1.call(OperatorRetryWithPredicate.java:127)
    at rx.internal.schedulers.TrampolineScheduler$InnerCurrentThreadScheduler.enqueue(TrampolineScheduler.java:73)
    at rx.internal.schedulers.TrampolineScheduler$InnerCurrentThreadScheduler.schedule(TrampolineScheduler.java:52)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorRetryWithPredicate$SourceSubscriber.onNext(OperatorRetryWithPredicate.java:79)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorRetryWithPredicate$SourceSubscriber.onNext(OperatorRetryWithPredicate.java:45)
    at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$WeakSingleProducer.request(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:276)
    at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:209)
    at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$JustOnSubscribe.call(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:138)
    at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$JustOnSubscribe.call(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:129)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
    at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10307)
    at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10274)
    at rx.observables.BlockingObservable.blockForSingle(BlockingObservable.java:445)
    at rx.observables.BlockingObservable.single(BlockingObservable.java:342)
    at com.netflix.client.AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.executeWithLoadBalancer(AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.java:117)
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.feign.ribbon.LoadBalancerFeignClient.execute(LoadBalancerFeignClient.java:63)
    ... 35 more
```

Also do bear in mind I was following the Spring Cloud Contract WireMock documentation [here](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-contract/multi/multi__spring_cloud_contract_wiremock.html) and I looked through their Github examples [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-contract/tree/master/samples). But the results are common in that most tests or implementations are using `RestTemplate` rather than `Feign`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should give a static server list to Ribbon which contains *localhost*.

Firstly you should define your LocalRibbonClientConfiguration as ContextConfiguration at the head of test class.

```
@RunWith (SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest (classes = TestApplication.class, webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.NONE)
@ContextConfiguration (classes = {LocalRibbonClientConfiguration.class})
```

---

Use WiremockClassRule with WireMockConfiguration.

```
@ClassRule
public static WireMockClassRule wiremock = new WireMockClassRule(WireMockConfiguration.options().dynamicPort());
```

---

```
@TestConfiguration
public static class LocalRibbonClientConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ServerList<Server> ribbonServerList() {
        return new StaticServerList<>(new Server("localhost", wiremock.port()));
    }
}
```

It goes without problem.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this. I ended up using [Pact](https://github.com/DiUS/pact-jvm) with `PactProvider` and `PactVeriification`. I will probably post it below.

Comment: Using pact I had a [ConsumerTest](https://github.com/Artemas-Muzanenhamo/gov-poc/blob/develop/license-service/src/test/java/com/gov/zw/client/IdentityClientTest.java) and then the [ProviderVerificationTest](https://github.com/Artemas-Muzanenhamo/gov-poc/blob/develop/identity-service/src/test/java/com/gov/zw/provider/IdentityProviderTest.java)

Comment: Is there possible to inject wiremock instance into spring config without using `@TestConfiguration` ?